# Listen to token being removed from local storage and update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm connecting user authorization with the backend. When I receive `accessToken`, I store it in
local storage. When it expires, I remove it from local storage.

Saving and removing from local storage happens in my service file, and the below code is a part of my context file from which I manage my global session state.

The first `useEffect` keeps the user logged in when the page is reloaded. In the second one, I wanted to
automatically log the user out whenever one of the endpoints returns `401 unauthorized` (so when
`accessToken` is removed from local storage).

However, the second one does not reload when the token is removed. Even if I put there a `console.log`, it doesn't show up in the console. It just doesn't even run.

Why is `useEffect` not reacting to local storage item change?

```
const [sessionState, setSessionState] = useState<SessionStateType>({
    status: "anon",
    accessToken: null,
});

useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    if (token) {
      setSessionState({ status: "auth", accessToken: token });
    }
  }, []);

  const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
      setSessionState({ status: "anon", accessToken: null });
    }
  }, [token]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no listening to local storage changes in your code, and it's not the behavior by default. And even if it was the case, you need to somehow re-render your component to have your `useEffect` with `token` as a dependency to re-run.

A solution is to set up an event listener for `storage` in your `useEffect`, and remove that `token` that's outside, like so:

```
// const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
useEffect(() => {
  // on page load
  const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  if (!token) {
    setSessionState({ status: "anon", accessToken: null });
  }

  // when the storage change
  window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    if (!token) {
      setSessionState({ status: "anon", accessToken: null });
    }
  });
}, []);
```

But for this event to run, anytime you clear the storage, immediately call a `dispatchEvent` like so:

```
localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
```

That last step is needed because [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) works this way:

> The `storage` event of the `Window` interface fires when a storage area (`localStorage`) has been modified in the context of `another document`.

So this `dispatchEvent` is needed as we need to listen to changes in the same document as well.